# React keys and Reconciliation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a use-case where I have a dynamically generated JSX element that I need to be altered between renders but not re-created.  To this end I have assigned it a unique, constant key but despite this I am finding that sometimes React will still recreate the element instead of merely altering it, despite the fact that nothing else in the DOM has changed!  When I read the documentation on this nowhere do I see an explicit guarantee that React will respect the key prop in its reconciliation.  They are described as 'hints' to React.  So are these occasional variances to be expected, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible to store whatever it is that is so important in a Flux Store, and have the component merely fetch the date there?

Comment: what do you mean by "re-create" the element? You mean re-render?

Comment: By 're-create' I mean React destroyed the element and created a new one, as opposed to altered by which I mean React took the existing DOM element and just changed some of its attributes.  In both scenarios the render function would have run.  My understanding of this is informed by this documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html.

Comment: I think I solved this issue.  The element was being re-rendered because, besides the alteration to the element itself, its order in the DOM had changed.  I stupidly failed to realize this.  So it seems like if you want React to only alter and not re-render an element you must, besides giving it a unique key, make sure that its order among its siblings has not changed.  If anyone else wants to chime in with some knowledge it would be good too.